# Minify my css file in laravel

Tags: laravel

Is there any tool that helps me in organizing my css files.I have so many css files in my app and i have to include them one by one like `{!! Html::script('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}` and others so that the load time  of the app won't also take long. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In laravel, you get a default `app.css` it contains bootstrap css and some others also. They are in minimized form.

If you are using laravel 5.4 you can enter css in sass format in `/resources/assets/sass/` and register it in `webpack.mix.js` file.
 Then by running `npm run production` you get all the files in minimized form. Which reduce the size and increase security.

You can also create all the css files in one single file to reduce effort to insert all.

If you are using laravel 5.3 or below then you can use `gulp` to minimize the files.

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.2 sir

Comment: @A.Sand If you are using laravel 5.3 or below (laravel 5.2) you can use gulp to minimize css and js files. Please dont call me sir beacuse I am still a child of 14 years old

Answer (score 1):

> **Laravel Elixir**
>
> Here is the official documentation and complete guide how can you minify css as well as js files in your application. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to "compile" files to production mode and minify any CSS/JS:

```
npm run production
```